# Отображение картинки в Recycler через Picasso

Tags: java, android, picasso

Добрый день!

Если вы решили это читать - извините за неприятный код.

Проблема вот в чём : Всё вроде бы работает, только вот Picasso не отображает картинки. Сайт парсится, ссылки достаются, но не отображаются, причем очень странный момент: если в дебаге поставить стопы на куске кода с Picasso, то они отображаютсяа, а если просто запускать - нет.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
LinearLayoutManager verticalLinearLayoutManager;
RecyclerAdapter adapter;
public Elements title;
public ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NewThread nt = new NewThread();
    nt.execute();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    verticalLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(verticalLinearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.addAll(titleList);
}

private class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addAll(ArrayList<String> titleList) {
        int pos = 0;
        this.linkList.addAll(titleList);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(pos, this.linkList.size());
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_card, parent, false);

        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(linklist.get(position)).into(holder.image3);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return linkList.size();
    }
}

private class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     public ImageView image3;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image3 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
    }

    public void bind(String s) {

    }
}

        public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
                Document doc;
                try {

                    doc = Jsoup.connect("https://habrahabr.ru/").get();
                    titleList.clear();
                    Elements link3 = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");

                    for(Element el:link3){
                        titleList.add(el.absUrl("src"));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Хочу порекомендовать к использованию библиотеку Glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide - аналог Picasso. С Picasso возникали непонятные проблемы, которые удалось обойти Glidом. Интерфейс очеь похож на пикассо, не доставит проблем перейти. Еще один момент заметил, Вы в onBindViewHolder написали цикл, что не есть верно, так как onBindViewHolder вызывается для каждого view отдельно, а вы получается присваиваете одному и тому же view всегд последнюю картинку. Получите ссылку: String link = linkList.get(position)  и уже ее передайте в пикассо или глайд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы заполняете ваш список в другом потоке. Вызов recyclerView.setAdapter() происходит в момент, когда NewThread еще не выполнен.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  adapter.addAll(titleList);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

onPostExecute будет вызван как только данные будут загружены, таким образом будут готовы к отображению. В дебаге у вас получалось, так как данные успевали загрузиться до присвоения адаптера.

```
NewThread nt = new NewThread();
nt.execute(); // выполняется в другом потоке, соответсвенно нельзя ждать что после этого вызова данные для отображения будут готовы
```

Comment: Но нельзя же в главном потоке работать с сетью - будет ошибка.
Что тогда делать?

Comment: Правильно, получайте данные так как и получаете сейчас, просто добавте строку adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() в onPostExecute; Она укажет адаптеру что были внесены изменения в data source. onPostExecute всегда выполняется в основном потоке (UI).... Внес еще небольшую правку в ответ.

Comment: Да, спасибо!
Это именно то, что нужно!